# "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." What am I doing wrong with the default CentOS VNC configuration?

Tags: centos, vnc

I'm trying to configure a little PC settop for work that will mostly be used as a remote backup server (basically just something that exists for the extremely remote possibility that our data center disappears in the rapture) at my employer's home. I'm using a NUC5CPYH with CentOS 7. It's got a 2TB laptop hard drive and 8 GB of RAM.  I installed from the minimal CD, added GNOME. Updated to today's repos with `yum upgrade`.

Basically, the relevant extent of my configuration can be found [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-on-centos-7). Other than shell utilities I like (e.g., tmux) I haven't added much else that didn't come along with the commands:

```
yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"
yum install vnc-server
```

My biggest deviation from that howtoforge instruction method is my exec line set VNC to display at 1024x768:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l <user> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1024x768"
```

(where <user> is obviously the right username)

I wanted one remote desktop user, my employer, who would be able to access it remotely if ever necessary.  Mostly that would just be on his home LAN.  The intended X display is :1.

By and large everything I've tried works beautifully except remote desktop.  GNOME works fine locally.  However, when I try to VNC in several problems occur.

### Problem 1

I can't see the mouse cursor at any time when I VNC in.  It's obviously responding to mouse input.  I just can't see the cursor in the client.

### Problem 2

This error message taking up the whole tigervnc client window saying "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again." Very helpful, thank you. [image: "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."]

Per Problem 1, I can hit that "Log Out" button even though I have to hover around until I find it with the mouse cursor. Once I hit it, the screen looks like: [image: What happens after I close the error message]

At this point, I can repeat the process by restarting the VNC server with systemctl.

### Other details

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux [REDACTED].[REDACTED] 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 23 17:05:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The configuration file `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service` looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1024x768"
PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm assuming this doesn't matter, but I'm using tigervnc client on my home desktop running ArchLinux to access this.

Comment: Try using other platform & VNC client to access your server. That way you will know if problem is on server or client side.

Answer (score 1):

I use xrdp with some success on my Centos and Debian boxes. That way you won't rely on (not-uptodate) VNC-Client-Software.

In [this](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html) Tutorial you will also find firewall and SELinux settings for an installation of xrdp on Centos 7.

Comment: Hi and welcome on serverfault. Please try to summurise the content of tutorial : links can become broken :)